# htaccess - Redirect content inside subdomain, but not subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, subdomain

I'm currently using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://blog.domain.com/(.*) /blog/article/$1
```

To redirect old links like: blog.domain.com/article-title to www.domain.com/blog/article/article-title

However, when I simply go to blog.domain.com, it's taking me to www.domain.com/blog/article.

This is an unintended side effect.  I'd like blog.domain.com/ itself to redirect simply to www.domain.com/blog but the content inside of that to redirect as above (which works fine.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(.*)` will match a slash followed by zero or more characters, which means `http://blog.example.com/` would match and be processed by this rule. Changing it to `/(.+)` would only match a slash followed by one or more characters, which should stop the root redirection. What about something like this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/blog
RedirectMatch 301 /(.+) http://www.example.com/blog/article/$1
```

This would work if put in a virtual host for blog.example.com, assuming [www.]example.com was in a separate virtual host. If you're handling them all from within a single vhost, this would redirect to itself endlessly. The only way I know of to handle it in one vhost is with mod_rewrite. Something like this, perhaps:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example.com/blog/article/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Nice, that helps a little, but I'd still like blog.domain.com to redirect to domain.com/blog

Comment: If you put the snippet above in a virtual host for your blog subdomain, it should do just that (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Thanks!  Your code worked when I tailored it to mine, I didn't see your edit :)

`Redirect 301 http://blog.domain.com http://www.domain.com/blog
RedirectMatch 301 http://blog.domain.com/(.+) http://www.domain.com/blog/article/$1`

Comment: Great! I didn't realize you could format the `Redirect` rules quite like that ([the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) seems to imply the first URL has to start with a slash), but if it works, it works.

Comment: Arg, it's not working again.  blog.domain.com/article-name does not redirect to domain.com/blog/article/article-name :( any ideas?  When I use the slashes like in your example I get a redirect loop

Comment: Error 500, this is the closest I could get:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.blog.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/article/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Sorry, silly typo. There were a couple of other mistakes as well. Let me know if it's any better now.